# Wordpress Error on Login - Too Many Redirects

Tags: wordpress

I installed a clean version of the latest wordpress and set up a vhost for it correctly.

Everything works fine. The thing is when i am on the login form and i am trying to login to my backend i am getting the error. "Too many redirects" and i can't seem to fix it.

Does anyone here facing the same problem and can help me to fix it?

What i tried so far is that i reinstalled everything, but that doesnt fix the problem either. then i created a new user and tried with that one, still the same prob.

Anyone having an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Access the file `wp-config.php` and add the following.

define('WP_HOME','http://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yourdomain.com');

Replace `yourdomain.com` with the your website URL.

**Step 2:** Delete your current `.htaccess` file and create a new .htaccess file with the following contents.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This could resolve the issue.

Comment: Dude, you are a genius and you solved my issue. Thanks for your help!